# MongoDb sort in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have to sort a mongodb collection in ruby via the mongodb driver.When I sort in the db directly using

```
db.zipper.find().sort({"value":-1})
```

But when I do the same thing in ruby,the collection is not getting sorted.I am using

```
coll = db.collection('zipper')
coll.find().sort({"value":-1})
```

Tell me where I am going wrong.I tried with

```
coll.find.sort(:value,:desc)
```

But that too is in vain.Tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the sort options as an array of key value pairs, eg:

```
 coll.find({}, :sort => ['value',-1])
```

With the Ruby driver you can also use `desc` or `descending` as semantic equivalents for the `-1` reverse sort order:

```
 coll.find({}, :sort => ['value','desc'])
 coll.find({}, :sort => ['value','descending'])
```

Comment: It works for me after i changed the array to object :   :sort => {'value' => -1})

Answer (score 0):

With newer Ruby and Mongo drivers you can use hash syntax like so:

```rb
coll.find({}, sort: {value: -1})
```